# Repository pattern usage

Tags: c#, repository, entity

I need some advice regarding repository pattern. Let's assume i have `UserBal` which stands for business logic which uses `UserRepositoryDal` where all database logic for that entity stands (queries to table `T_Users` because my repositories uses stored procedures.) In my database i have table `T_Users` and `T_UserTypes`. In `T_User` table there is relation to `T_UserTypes`. It means each user has own user type.

In my application i've created:

- UserBal - for business logic and uses UserRepositoryDal
- UserRepositoryDal - all database logic to get data for 'T_Users'

Repository have common functionality like: `GetAll(), Insert etc..`

My entites are:

```
public class User
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name{ get; set; }
     public int FK_UserType { get; set; }
}

public class UserType
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

I am not sure at this point whether should i create also repository for table `T_UserTypes` like: `UserTypeRepositoryDal` and for business logic `UserTypeBal` which would use `UserTypeRepositoryDal` ?

or should i just modify my User class instead of:

```
public int FK_UserType { get; set; }
```

change to:

```
public UserType UserType { get; set; }
```

so there would not be `UserTypeBal` and `UserTypeRepositoryDal` at all

Nevertheless when in application i would like to get list of `UserType` for instance for combo box control or whatever i would not have `UserTypeRepositoryDal` with `GetAll()` so where should i put logic for `UserTypes` GetAll(). Should it be in `UserRepositoryDal`?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need one repository per table. A repository can encapsulate all data access required for a given entity. The record in the users table is associated with a record in the user types table by way of a foreign key. You can model this in C# as well by replacing the `User.FK_UserType` property with an actual `UserType` object. The UserRepositoryDal (which "UserRepository" is descriptive enough that you can drop the "Dal" suffix") can query the database appropriately using a JOIN:

```sql
SELECT users.a, users.b, userTypes.a, userTypes.b
FROM t_users users
    JOIN t_user_types ON ...
```

When you need to reuse database mappings from tables to objects, create a new class in C# just for the data mapping.

No need for a separate repository.

---

> Ok - let's say now i want to populate combobox with all UserTypes names and values as id to be taken later on when user selects something from that control. Where GetAll for UserType should be defined? in UserRepository as well?

This is honestly a good question, and one I have as well. Laiv mentioned adding a "lookup" which could be its own "repository" or data access class that specializes in generating the data for things like combo boxes. You can also add a `GetUserTypes()` method or a `UserTypes` property to the `UserRepository` that returns a collection of `UserType` objects, which you can use later on to create a new collection of combo box items.

I've used a property on the repository for lookup entities. Transforming them into combo box items is usually pretty easy:

```
var comboBoxItems = from userType in userRepository.UserTypes
                    select new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = userType.Name,
                        Value = userType.Id.ToString()
                    };
```

Comment: Ok - let's say now i want to populate combobox with all UserTypes names and values as id to be taken later on when user selects something from that control. Where GetAll for UserType should be defined? in UserRepository as well ?

Comment: Then Implement a lookup.

Comment: lookup - can you describe bit more please? I mean if i would not have UserTypeRepository i cannot just do: UserTypeBal.GetAll().

Comment: The lookup is more generic. A component that allows you to perform *get-all or get-by-id* queries of any entity without having to implement full-fledge repository for it. E.g: `lookup.GetAll(UserType.class); or lookup.Get(UserType.class, "id")`

Comment: @Laiv I really don't get what you offer. What does this lookup return and how can do this for all type of class? Generics? No no you can not say that :)

Comment: @Arie: I've updated my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: @GregBurghardt You should define how to load UserTypes and it is main question I think. Assume there are 10 user type but 1000000 user. I don't think you offer geting user types from distinct users. So, you need to create another query (SP here) to return user types. When you do that, it means one of UserRepository method returns list of UserType other than User. And, for me, it is against to Single Responsible Principle for UserRepository. That's why I offer creating for each repository or using generic repository.

Comment: @Engineert don't confuse generic with specialized.

Comment: @Laiv How can you specialized method's return type for kind of classes without using generics ?

Comment: You don't have to use generics. Casting also works. On the other hand, reposistories play a relevant role within the domain boundary. They are part of the domain what makes them bad as cross-cutting components. Unlike reposistories, lookups are less relevant  for the domain and they are totally agnostic to the things they retrieve. Lookups are like maps or sets. Or they usually are. That's why they are good as services discovery or locators. Reposistories also have a very concrete interface addressed to solve the needs of the business, the lookup usually have a very flat one (get).

Comment: The idea of a method in *UserRepository* is also good, and simpler than lookups. KISS is a good premise to follow in case of doubts.

Comment: @Laiv You offer many things but I can not see any advantages of them. Your attitude to Generics is a little bit redundant, for me. Anyway its your software world.

Comment: My attitude is biased by my experience . I used them a lot and after a while I came to the conclusion that they are not silver bullets and many of us over-use them. Once I gave up on doing everything generic my software improved in resilience and simplicity. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I hope adding Bal(Business access layer) and Dal(Data Access Layer) to name of classes are just for sample. Because it is really bad naming convention I think. Your layer name is enough to understand it.

And for your question, exactly what you need to do is creating `UserTypeRepositoryDal` and `UserTypeBal`. As you think, if you do not that, you can not get user type list directly or you would add another class and this would be against Single Responsibility Principle(SRP). Also, every development about `UserType` won't be placed on appropriate class.

Beyond this, you can add `public UserType UserType { get; set; }` on `User` entity even there is `FK_UserType`. This is good way to manage 1-1 or 1-n relations. It looks like :

```cs
public class User
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name{ get; set; }
     public int FK_UserType { get; set; }
     public UserType UserType { get; set; }
}
```

You can load `UserType` in `User` object by using `FK_UserType`. If you use ORM like Entity Framework, it can do this for you.

This way is proper to manage 1-1 and/or 1-n relations. If you have n-n relation, then you need relation table and its Bal and Dal classes.

Also, designing your repository and your entity class should not depend on whether you use Store Procedures or not.

And, to avoid creating too much repository classes, I recommend **Generic Repository Pattern**.

Comment: Am i understanding correctly that i need for every table in datatabase one repository class in my application? P.S I think i got better convention like: ( for entity) => User / (for business logic) => UserBusiness / (dal) UserRepository . What you think?

Comment: @Arie No, I can't say it for all cases. In some cases, you can merge 2 table and act like one table or one really big table can represent with 2 entities. It is all up to your design. But If you think two table just have relation with each other and should manage separately,  it is better to create repository for each one and if you use Generic Repository Pattern, you do not need to create each concrete repository per table. Just passing entity to Generic Repository will be enough for you.

Comment: i see but by saying "merge two tables" - you mean to create repository which could have two more concrete repositories like: OrderItemsRepository which would use OrderRepository and ItemRepository or it's something other you had on mind. Thanks for answer

Comment: maybe better example would be if i would have T_Orders table and table T_Items table then we would have table T_Orders_Items going by our logic we could have repository OrdersRepository and repository ItemsRepository. Should i then have class like OrderServiceBusiness which would use both repositories or additional RepositoryX which could take as parameter both OrderRepository and ItemsRepository and then OrderServiceBusiness would consume RepositoryX? How you would accomplish that?

Comment: `I highly recommend Generic Repository Pattern` what a horrible advice :-) . Run away from generic things. You are not implementing a framework or a library for reuse in all sort of applications.

Comment: @Laiv It can depend what software architecture you use, I think. I like to keep repositories simple. But I usually use Generic Repository with Entity Framework. It could be hard to use generic one without ORM. Thus, I will remove "highly" for you :)

Comment: Generic components are the seed of the evil. No matter the architecture.

Comment: @Laiv, I was with you re avoiding generic repositories. "*Generic components are the seed of the evil*" is just plain silly though.

Comment: Two down vote without any reason or I miss something?

Comment: @Engineert can you answer to my last comment please?

Comment: in some article i read that it's good to have 1:1 - table : repository and then create something like service class for instance OrderService which could take in ctor few repositories like Orderrepository, ItemRepository and UserRepository and use those repository in that service. There is also mentioned that one repository should not have referecen to ther repository. So means i should be createing service classes which could consume diffrent repositories on theuir need. Other example could be OrderStaffService which could also take few rpositories and do some staff there. What ypu think?

Comment: @Arie As I mention before, It is up to your design. Assume there are User table which have Name, Surname,...  columns and Address table Adress, ZipCode, City, Country.. columns. You can represent all this columns on one entity with one repository which has Name, Surname, Adress, zipCode, City, Country ... columns. It is just sample. Also you can split a big table and represent with 2 repository by the contrary approach.

Comment: @Arie You don't need to consume different repositories on service class. You can call proper service classes, which already consume related repositories, in the service class.